# Sending tokens out on coinpayments success payment using Web3py

Tags: gas, nonce, django, web3.py

I'm writing Django app and want to send out tokens using Web3 once Coinpayments sends me callback about successfull payment. The problem is that Coinpayments sends multiple callbacks at once and just in one case tokens are sending, other callbacks get `replacement transaction underpriced` error. I've already tried to use solutions like add +1 to `nonce` or remove this parameter, but that doesn't help me because transactions are still building with the same nonce. How can that be fixed or what am I doing wrong?

```
class CoinpaymentsIPNPaymentView(BaseCoinpaymentsIPNView):
    def post(self, request, order_id, *args, **kwargs):
        status = int(request.POST.get('status'))
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
        order.status = request.POST.get("status_text")
        if not status >= 100:
            order.save()
            return JsonResponse({"status": status})
        amount = Decimal(request.POST.get('amount1'))
        record = Record.objects.create(
            user=order.user,
            type='i',
            amount=amount,
        )
        order.record = record
        order.save()

        gold_record = GoldRecord.objects.get(from_record=record)

        contract = w3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=ABI_JSON)
        transaction = contract.functions.transfer(order.user.wallet.address, int(gold_record.amount * 10 ** 18)).buildTransaction({
            'chainId': 1,
            'gas': 70000,
            'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(WALLET_ADDRESS)                      # address where all tokens are stored
        })
        signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY)  # signing with wallet's above private key
        tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
        print(tx_hash.hex())
        tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

        return JsonResponse({"status": status})
```